# libusb - configure error (libudev not installed)

Tags: linux, cygwin, libusb, udev, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to cross-compile the [libusb v1.0.19](http://libusb.info/) library using the **arm-verifone-linux-gnueabi-gcc** compiler in [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), but at the end of the **configure** call it shows this error:

> udev support requested but libudev not installed.

Here is my configure call:

```
./configure CC=arm-verifone-linux-gnueabi-gcc --host=arm-linux


checking operating system... Linux
checking for library containing clock_gettime... -lrt
checking libudev.h usability... no
checking libudev.h presence... no
checking for libudev.h... no
configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"
configure: WARNING: cache variable lt_cv_path_LD contains a newline
```

The error clearly says that libudev is not available on my setup, so I tried to google for the libudev source, so I can cross-compile it as well, but unfortunately I couldn't find the source. Where can I find the libudev source or how I can get around this error?

---

UPDATE:
I was able to get rid of the "udev" error by running this configure line:

```
./configure CC=arm-verifone-linux-gnueabi-gcc --host=arm-linux --disable-udev
```

But after running "make", it shows:

```
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating libusb-1.0.pc
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libusb/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/doxygen.cfg
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: WARNING: cache variable lt_cv_path_LD contains a newline

user@g480 /usr/src/libusb-1.0.19
$ make
Makefile:264: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

```
./configure --host=arm-verifone-linux-gnueabi
```